# getting null pointer exception while instantiating ServiceClient

Tags: java, servlets

I have made a client where i am creating a new object of ServiceClient. My code is:

```
private ServiceClient getClient(String action, String eprType){
String webinfFolder = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF");
        try{
            if(wsSecurityEnabled){
                configContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(webinfFolder, webinfFolder + "/conf/axis2.xml");       
                serviceClient = new ServiceClient(configContext, null);
            }else{
                serviceClient = new ServiceClient();//Here i am getting nullpointerexception
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        targetEPR = new EndpointReference(eprType);
        serviceClient.setOptions(getOptions(action));       
        serviceClient.addHeader(getUserNameHeaderElement());
        System.out.println("Client Created");
        return serviceClient;
}
```

Since my wsSecurityEnabled is false it comes to this code serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
 and here i am getting nullpointer exception as:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:162)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:251)
    at cts.remon.cctv.client.Consumer.getClient(Consumer.java:573)
    at cts.remon.cctv.client.Consumer.requestCloseSession(Consumer.java:147)
    at cts.remon.cctv.client.Consumer.doPost(Consumer.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

How to solve this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the `init` method of your servlet

Comment: My client is Consumer.jsp which is getting redirected to Consumer.java servlet So the actual error that i am getting is at Consumer.java:573). and i haven't implemented the init method of servlet